# ENOTFOUND on paypal request?

Tags: paypal

I keep getting this in my logs:

```
problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.paypal.com api.paypal.com:443
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.paypal.com api.paypal.com:443]
  cause: 
   { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.paypal.com api.paypal.com:443]
     code: 'ENOTFOUND',
     errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: 'api.paypal.com',
     host: 'api.paypal.com',
     port: 443 },
  isOperational: true,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'api.paypal.com',
  host: 'api.paypal.com',
  port: 443 }
PAYPAL_ERROR {
  "cause": {
    "code": "ENOTFOUND",
    "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
    "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
    "hostname": "api.paypal.com",
    "host": "api.paypal.com",
    "port": 443
  },
  "isOperational": true,
  "code": "ENOTFOUND",
  "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
  "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
  "hostname": "api.paypal.com",
  "host": "api.paypal.com",
  "port": 443
}
```

Is paypal down or am i missing something as this seems to have been for several hours now. I am using https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK library.

Comment: did you solve it ?

Answer (score -2):

The issue was that my back-end server was not able to resolve paypal.

Comment: I think you should have posted your solution regardless